# iOS SpriteKit physics for a turn based game?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm currently working on a game that relies heavily on physics, that will determine if the player has lost. The game is working great most of the time but every once in awhile the physics plays out differently on one device from the other. The way it works is a person moves the piece and places it where they would like. The game then saves the state of all the pieces and ends the turn before the physics play out. This state is transferred to the other player so both players can see the turn actually take place. I would think that if every node is in the exact same position the physics would play out the same on both devices. Like I said they are very similar but sometimes they are different enough to create a false game over detection. Is there something I can do to make sure they are the same or a better way of sending the state between turns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been discovered by others [Sprite Kit's physics simulation is not deterministic](http://www.element84.com/comparing-sprite-kit-physics-to-direct-box2d.html).

You can't do anything to "fix" this behavior but you can always use Box2D directly with Sprite Kit, bypassing respectively forwarding all SK physics classes and properties to your own implementation.

Comment: When you say forwarding all SK physics class to my own implementation, would you subclass them and direct them to Box2D? Just looking for a direction to go in.

Comment: Hmmm that's one way but come to think of it it may be inefficient to subclass SKPhysicsBody/SKPhysicsWorld because it'll also initialize and use Sprite Kit's physics.